# Postgres eventually consistency Id

Tags: postgresql

Taken a table like this:

- create table mytable(id SERIAL, largeImage bytea);

Imagine 2 process (A, B) simultaneously do inserts:

Process A arrives first but contains a very large file.

After that Process B arrives but very small file.

- I suppose that inserts will work in paralell and consistency order (id assignament) is done  because nextval is assigned on arrives moment. (Maybe I am wrong).

Because the Process B file is small than process A, the Process B is faster thant Process A to save on disk. (my guess)

My questions:

1. Process A will be assigned with ID=1 a, d Process B will get Id=2. Thats correct?
2. It is posible (rare but possible) that "select * from mytable" will return only the ID=2 because save disk operation of Process A (Id=1) has not finished already?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, of course that all can happen, but that is no problem, is it?

Comment: Many Thanks Laurenz, so the problem occurs in my implementation that is processing batch regs using last Id processed as start for the next batch processing. I realized that I found older regs int table that i not processed because has not been found by select when was fired (race condition)). Maybe the best approach will be use xmin of the last record processed to set the offset for the next batch start process?

Comment: There is never an ordering in the database unless you explicitly serialize operations.

Comment: Thanks for pointed me in the right direction!!

Comment: "*using last Id processed as start for the next batch processing*" - if you are processing in batches, then why would you have two concurrent processes accessing the table? But either way, you always need to consider that sequences (`serial`) may contain gaps - from past transactions that were rolled back, or from ongoing transactions that you don't see yet (that are not yet committed).

Answer (score 0):

> Process A will be assigned with ID=1 and Process B will get Id=2. Thats correct?

Probably yes, but I have not tested it.

> It is posible (rare but possible) that `select * from mytable` will return only the ID=2 because save disk operation of Process A (Id=1) has not finished already?

This is possible for a variety of reasons and not only for a short period of time. Imagine the process that got the ID=1 crashes before it finishes the transaction. You will then never see a row with ID=1 in your table.

If you catch yourself assuming that `SERIAL` means "continuous", take a step back and redesign your data model. `SERIAL` rather means "automatic value that is guaranteed to be unique". It is a good idea for an ID, it is generally not appropriate for numbering.